# Proving limits using $\varepsilon$ - $\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis

Let 
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
(x-1)^2, & \text {if x $\in\Bbb Q$}\\
0, & \text {if x $\notin\Bbb Q$}\\
\end{cases}
$$

Prove that $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$ exists.

> Let $\varepsilon$ >0 and choose $\delta=\min\{\sqrt{\varepsilon},\varepsilon\}$

should the $\delta$ be only $\sqrt{\varepsilon}$ or the above is correct?

> When $x$ is rational: 
>   $$\begin{align}
> |(x-1)^2-0| & = |(x-1)^2|\\
> & = |x-1||x-1|\\
> & <(\sqrt{\varepsilon})^2\\
> & = \varepsilon
> \end{align}$$
>
> When $x$ is irrational:
>   $$\begin{align}
> |0-0|& = 0\\
> & <|x-1|\\
> & <\delta\\
> & = \varepsilon
> \end{align}$$

At this part, i'm not sure if i could write this: $$|x-1|<\delta<\sqrt{\varepsilon}<\varepsilon$$ - is this correct too?

> Therefore, $\lim_{x\to1} f(x)$ exists.

Comment: Yes, it looks fine.

Comment: @ Zev Chonoles yes i have a question, could you help me check if the working is correct?

Comment: Two remarks. First: By estimating $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$ for $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ you assume the limit to be $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=0$, don't you? Second: With $\delta<\sqrt{\epsilon}<\epsilon$ I do not get the definiton $\delta:=\min(\sqrt{\epsilon},\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of $\delta$ is o.k., albeit it could be simplified. Above all the argument in the large grey box is not self-explaining, insofar as $|x-1|<\delta$ is tacitly assumed. I'd argue as follows:

For given $\epsilon>0$ put $\delta:=\sqrt{\epsilon}$. When $0<|x-1|<\delta$ then
$$|f(x)-0|\leq|x-1|^2<\delta^2=\epsilon\ ,$$
whether $x$ is rational or not. It follows that $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=0$.

Comment: well , this was the clean proof.OP should look at this too.

Answer (score 0):

You may choose $\delta $ to be $\sqrt\varepsilon$ or $min(\sqrt\varepsilon$ ,$\varepsilon$)

but not $\varepsilon$ .

For your second question  :   $ \varepsilon$ > $\sqrt\varepsilon$ doesn't hold for $0$<$\varepsilon$<1.

And with the above work , you also have proved the limit to be $0$ besides existence.